# Windows 64bit Powershell over SSH useable Terminal Text Editor/Pager, ideally small, portable, with vi grammar

Tags: windows, text-editor, ssh, terminal-emulator, powershell

I connect to a Windows Machine via SSH into a Powershell Terminal, and regularly need to made quick,small edits in text files on this Windows Computer, and others reachable via UNC syntax.

Currently I use the binary from the [vim console version for windows](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim80-586w32.zip), but it has drawing problems in my scenario: When you scroll lower than the last line in a file longer than the screen, all lines but the last disappear, and you have to force a redraw with ^L.

There is also a portable single-binary compile of nano.exe, but it has flaws, like non-functioning cursor keys. It also is pretty basic, no vi grammar, no syntax highlighting, but those I could live without for small edits.

For larger,more-involved edits on remote files I already use the excellent emacs/evil/tramp/sftp IDE running locally on my Linux.

Old Windows Versions up to 7/32bit included a very basic editor, that I used to use, but everything starting from 7/64bit does not have that editor anymore, so please don't suggest that one.

The editor vile does not even display anything over SSH in Powershell.

Comment: Hi Downvoter, I am new here, could you please elaborate on the reason. Or could somebody else please clue me in?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how portable it can be, and not exactly 'small', but [vim](https://www.vim.org/) does have console (including PowerShell) support.

[vile](http://invisible-island.net/vile/) and [elvis](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/) might also work, though I don't know almost anything about them other than that they're `vi` clones which support Windows.

Comment: vim.exe from Win32.zip in powershell via ssh from Linux has redraw problems: When you scroll down on a larger file, all lines but the last disappear, and you have to force a manual redraw with ^L. I will add to my question that I tried that too. Thank you anyway, have a +1

Comment: I tried vile, It completely fails to draw over SSH in Powershell. Both it and elvis are ancient, and do not look very maintained

Answer (score 0):

[Mosh](https://mosh.org/) is a shell designed for easy roaming, slow network connections and instant user responses

> Remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes.
>
> Mosh is a replacement for interactive SSH terminals. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.

The important thing is that it understands vi commands and predicts what will happen to show the text correctly

> ## Get rid of network lag.
>
> SSH waits for the server's reply before showing you your own typing. That can make for a lousy user interface. Mosh is different: it gives an instant response to typing, deleting, and line editing. **It does this adaptively and works even in full-screen programs like emacs and vim.** On a bad connection, outstanding predictions are underlined so you won't be misled.

If you're remoting from Windows then see this [Portable Windows Mosh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19929267/995714). You can keep a portable version of Mobaxterm which will include both mosh and vi

Comment: For other questions, "mosh" is a good answer, but not for mine. I'm afraid, you misunderstood. Thanks anyway for your time and effort

Comment: @AlexStragies just run a mosh server on Windows and ssh into it. You should use a 3rd party terminal like Mobaxterm, as Windows console might not support ANSI codes very well, which results in glitches when running vi